# Ansible fails after changing ansible_python_interpreter

Tags: python-2.7, ansible

After changing the default python path ansible cannot run or load any python library

```
{  
   "changed":false,
   "failed":true,
   "module_stderr":"Shared connection to x.x.x.x closed.\r\n",
   "module_stdout":"Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1510222878.61-64380131096787/setup.py\", line 123, in <module>\r\n    f.write(z.read('ansible_module_setup.py'))\r\n  File \"/home/user/python/lib/p`enter code here`ython2.7/zipfile.py\", line 935, in read\r\n    return self.open(name, \"r\", pwd).read()\r\n  File \"/home/user/python/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py\", line 1010, in open\r\n    close_fileobj=should_close)\r\n  File \"/home/user/python/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py\", line 526, in __init__\r\n    self._decompressor = zlib.decompressobj(-15)\r\nAttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decompressobj'\r\n",
   "msg":"MODULE FAILURE",
   "rc":0
}
```

i've also tried to run ansible -m ping i get pretty much the same result

```
{  
   "changed":false,
   "failed":true,
   "module_stderr":"Shared connection to x.x.x.x closed.\r\n",
   "module_stdout":"Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1510223942.9-58678212493208/ping.py\", line 123, in <module>\r\n    f.write(z.read('ansible_module_ping.p 
y'))\r\n  File \"/home/user/python/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py\", line 935, in read\r\n    return self.open(name, \"r\", pwd).read()\r\n  File \"/home/user/python/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py\", line 1010, in open\r\
n    close_fileobj=should_close)\r\n  File \"/home/user/python/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py\", line 526, in __init__\r\n    self._decompressor = zlib.decompressobj(-15)\r\nAttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no a
ttribute 'decompressobj'\r\n",
   "msg":"MODULE FAILURE",
   "rc":0
}
```

ansible 2.3.2.0

python 2.7.11

any help would be very much appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and were only able to solve it by downgrading to Ansible 2.1.6.0.

In this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/25941) people are reporting similar issues and linking it to incompatible Ansible/Ubuntu versions:

> I'v had this issue on Ubuntu server 16.04 and 14.04 when using the latest ansible (2..3.1.0). After going back to Ansible version 2.2.2.0 on Ubuntu server 14.04 the problem was gone. So it seems like it's a issue of ansible 2.3.1.0 on Ubuntu generally.